# Lua: Escape string and write file

Tags: lua

I create the function writefile:

```
 function writefile(output,msgid)       
    file = io.open(output, "a")
    if (file) then                  
        file:write('msgid "' .. msgid .. '"')       
        file:close()
    else
        print("can't open file")
    end
end
```

parameter is :

```
output = output.txt
msgid =  "We can overcome anything!"
```

I want to ouput in file is `msgid "\"We can overcome anything!\""`

I don't want `msgid =  ""We can overcome anything!""`

How can I solve this?

Comment: If you need to escape quotes in the value (you don't have any quotes in the value of `msgid` here by the way) then you get to use [`string.gsub`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-string.gsub) to do it.

Comment: Ok It's work. thank man,

Comment: @EtanReisner: Don't post a comment as an answer.

Comment: @NicolBolas It wasn't an answer. It was part of an answer. An answer would involve example code and/or a quote from the manual. Neither of which I wanted to spend the time putting together. I'm also fairly certain there are other questions this could reasonably be a duplicate of but I didn't have the time to go looking.

Comment: @EtanReisner: No, it was a answer; just not a very *good* one. Leaving a answer-comment is worse than leaving a low-quality answer. By doing so, you solve the user's problem, but leaves the question in the "Unanswered" queue, even though it has an answer. That's bad, especially for low-visibility tags.

Comment: @NicolBolas You are right about the Unanswered bit. I still don't like the idea of getting VLQ flagged or supplying a VLQ answer but I'll certainly think more carefully about VLQ-answer comments in the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your intent is to have the string be escaped under Lua's escaping rules, then you should employ [`string.format`'s special `%q` formatting code](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-string.format):

```
file:write(string.format("msgid "%q"", msgid))
```

Comment: `msgid` makes me think of gettext so I'm not sure lua quoting rules are entirely correct here (though they are probably pretty close though I'm not sure what beyond double quotes in the original the OP would need escaped).

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
file:write('msgid "\\"' .. msgid .. '"\\"')
```

What I'm doing here is using a \ to escape another . We can't put it there directly because in Lua it's an escape character.

Comment: You can always escape the escape character. So "\\" in a Lua string becomes a `\` character.

Comment: @NicolBolas A `` character?

Comment: That should have been a \, but it seems you can't put them in code formatting.

Comment: @NicolBolas Oh, strange. Also thanks, I didn't realize \\ worked.

Comment: @NicolBolas Use 3 backticks: ```\```